# how to solve this ionic angular error while building it on android?

Tags: ionic-framework

when I am running this command  ionic cap run android -l --external, it shows the error as below in the image
[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsRq2.png).
How to solve this and  build app in android

I tried to delete node module and reinstalled and run command but then its not working.